Spark Shuffle FetchFailedException for large dataset in emr
My job takes a input data of 400 TB parquet dataset from s3. This job runs with 250 r716x large (each having 64 vCore, 488 GiB memory). The job fails with below error org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException.
Spark Submit:
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=268435456 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.rebalancePartitionsSmallPartitionFactor=.5 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum=30000 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout=8000 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=50000s  --conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g \
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.05 --conf spark.memory.fraction=.8 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.completed=0.99 \
--conf spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold=4000000 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1 \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=3000 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=36g --conf spark.driver.memory=60g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.output.enabled=true \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/hadoop/.config/certs/InternalAndExternalTrustStore.jks" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC " \
test.py

Code:
spark.sql(''' create or replace temporary view vwds_cnt_output as
    select
      k
    , m
    , count(distinct(psen, psed)) as kaw
    , count(distinct (psen, psed, pate)) as kt
      from vt
      group by k,m ''')

finaldf000=spark.sql(''' select * from vwds_cnt_output ''')
test_data00='s3://sea/seed/ktr/'
finaldf000.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(test_data00)






this EMR? and can you attach the full stack trace of a failed task.

2024-09-16 16:18:11,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor (ContainersLauncher #2): container_1726499754657_0001_01_000850 was deactivated
2024-09-16 16:18:11,995 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanagner exited with a non-zero exit code 143

implies the spark worker process probably crashed. there should be logs somewhere

I have added the spill size. Is it ok to increase shuffle partition count here or more nodes?
